# PL/SQL Speeding up long function

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

I am looking to speed up the following PL/SQL function. Right now it has run for over 2 hours with no sign of completing. We aborted that one and attempting it again with a EXIT WHEN of 20 and it still shows no signs of actually completing.

We are running these through SQLDeveloper 17.3, and each of the (4) tables has about 15k rows.

The goal is to grab all of the SSN's in our database and change the first character to an illegal char and the last 2 characters to a random A-Z combination. We then have to update that SSN in every table that uses it (4).

```
declare
    v_random varchar2(2); 
    v_origin_ssn varchar2(100);
    v_working_start varchar2(100);
    v_working_middle varchar2(100);
    v_new_ssn varchar2(100);
begin

    for o in (
        select distinct ssn  --loop all rows in tbl_customer
        from program_one.tbl_customer
    )
    loop
        if regexp_like(o.ssn, '^[A-Za-z9].*[A-Z]$') then continue; --if this is already scrambled, skip
        else 
            select dbms_random.string('U', 2) --create random 2 cap letters
                into v_random
            from dual;

            v_origin_ssn := o.ssn; --set origin ssn with the existing ssn

            if regexp_like(o.ssn, '^[A-Za-z]') --if first char is already alpha, leave it alone, otherwise 9
                then v_working_start := substr(o.ssn, 1, 1);
                else v_working_start := 9; 
            end if;

            v_working_middle := substr(o.ssn, 2, 6); --set middle ssn with the unchanged numbers

            v_new_ssn := v_working_start||v_working_middle||v_random; --create new sanitized ssn

            update program_one.tbl_customer --update if exists in tbl_customer
            set ssn = v_new_ssn
            where ssn = v_origin_ssn;

            commit;

            update program_one.tbl_mhc_backup --update if exists ssn tbl_mhc_backup
            set ssn = v_new_ssn
            where ssn = v_origin_ssn;

            commit;

            update program_two.tbl_waiver --update if exists ssn tbl_waiver
            set ssn = v_new_ssn
            where ssn = v_origin_ssn;

            commit;

            update program_two.tbl_pers --update if exists in tbl_pers
            set ssan = v_new_ssn
            where ssan = v_origin_ssn;

            commit;

        end if;

        --dbms_output.put_line(v_origin_ssn||' : '||v_new_ssn); --output test string to verify working correctly

    end loop;

end;
```

Comment: Is three a reason you're doing row-by-row updates? Or committing so frequently? And could the updates just be blocked by uncommitted changes in another session?

Comment: What is the session waiting for during execution?

Comment: If I were you, I’d create a new table that holds the old and new values (which you ought to be able to populate via a single `insert into ... select ...` statement), which you could then use to update the values in the other tables using either an update or (more likely) a merge statement. Doing it in bulk ought to be far quicker than your row-by-row (aka slow-by-slow) approach.

Comment: @alexpoole the development server we were running it on was unavailable during our testing, so there shouldn’t be any competing changes. When we left today we have it committing every 20 loopsinstead of after every update.

Comment: @boneist would that work with a view as well? Adding table to the schema, even temporary, is a releases level worth of paperwork.

Comment: @danninta no, not really, if you’re using dbms_random to populate things; it would produce different results every time you queried the view, whereas the table would store the results and keep them the same across the entire procedure. Is this something you would only run in non-production environments? It sounds like a data obfuscation exercise.

Comment: @boneist yes It would never be run in production. Up to our pre-prod environment we are free to do whatever, but once we get there it becomes a big fiasco to touch the schema. I will ask that question in our stand up tomorrow though.

Comment: One speedup that will work is to include ROWID in your select from program_one.tbl_customer. Then when you do the update on program_one.tbl_customer, instead of matching on SSN, match on ROWID. There is nothing faster in Oracle that matching on ROWID. My other concern is that the tables have proper indexes and statistics. That will make a huge difference.

Comment: Please **edit your question** and include: 1) rowcounts for each of the four tables; 2) indexes on each of the tables; 3) full DDL for each of the tables; 4) query plan for each of the statements (1 SELECT, 4 updates). Thanks.

Comment: @bonist: I support your suggestion and wrote some example code. damninta: For your standup: Just suggest to do a test run on a life sized copy first to get the timings. I'm sure it will be blazingly fast. Maybe do it in a separate schema, maybe involve the DBAs. In any case, this is the proper, industry standard way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it without a function in plain SQL:

Create a table with old and new ssn:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_ssn AS
  SELECT ssn, '9'||substr(ssn,2,6)||dbms_random.string('U',2) as new_ssn
    FROM (SELECT distinct ssn FROM program_one.tbl_customer);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ui_tmp_ssn ON tmp_ssn(ssn, new_ssn);
EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(null,'tmp_ssn');
```

... and then update the tables one by one:

```
MERGE INTO program_one.tbl_customer z USING tmp_ssn q ON (z.ssn=q.ssn)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE z.ssn = q.new_ssn;
COMMIT;

MERGE INTO program_one.tbl_mhc_backup z USING tmp_ssn q ON (z.ssn=q.ssn)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE z.ssn = q.new_ssn;
COMMIT;

etc
```

If that is still to slow, I'd do

```
RENAME tbl_customer to tbl_customer_old;
CREATE TABLE tbl_customer as
  SELECT s.new_ssn as ssn, t.col1, t.col2, ... , t.coln
    FROM tbl_customer_old t JOIN tmp_ssn s USING(ssn);
DROP TABLE tbl_customer_old;
```

Comment: So far this is basically the method we are using. On our slowest development server it ran at about 180 seconds per table. We are still running it as a function, but creating the temp table to insert into first and then running a merge after has been very quick. I will wait to accept the answer until tomorrow.